# Popup textview editor (Formatting) Android

Tags: android, popup, background-color

I want to create text editor in android and set It to main activity
Below is my screenshot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/popup"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:alpha="0.92">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Format your Text Style Here"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popupMainText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is a simple popup"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Font Size"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

        <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.14"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="5">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/font1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Font 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/font2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Font 2" />

        <Button
            android:id ="@+id/colorRed"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_red_round"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            />

    </GridLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**button_red_round.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/red_id">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:color="#ffffff" android:width="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
            <size android:width="30dp" android:height="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**MainActivity.java**

This code crash my application

```
colorRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   popupMainText.setBackground(colorRed.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_red_round));
            }
    });
```

I want button click event to set color for preview and main activity
but my application is unable to open after event is apply to main activity

Comment: Do you have any error logs? What is the problem?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.name/com.package.name.SingleViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: That's not easy to read. I'd recommend editing your original post to show the error logs

Comment: thanks for your advice as I am new to android can you please suggest me some reference to format text in popup. It will help me in that case

Comment: Could you post your java code that caused the error? I think I understand better what you are trying to do now

Comment: colorRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popupMainText.setBackground(colorRed.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_red_round));
            }
        });

Comment: Please post that as an edit to your question so that it has better formatting

Comment: Please check...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148541/discussion-between-maclean-sochor-and-parasarora1303).